# Insert image in textarea when button is pressed using javascript or jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have design one textarea and button in html. i want to insert image in textarea when button is pressed. how it is possible in javascript or jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Textareas can only contain text.

Answer (score 1):

Textareas can only contain text, but you can overlap elements. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2qMb3/1/

This uses a styled div instead of an image, but you can easily use an image instead of the div.

Answer (score 0):

As other said TextArea only contains Text but, you can try something like this:

```
<textarea id="x" rows="5" cols="20">hellooo</textarea>

$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('#x').css('background',urlOfImage)
});
```

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/dhtml/showit.asp?filename=trydhtml_form_bg_textarea) is a working example; you have to manipulate it according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor such as [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to add simple CSS to the textarea on click

The HTML

```
<textarea id="message" rows="2" cols="20"></textarea>
<input type="button" value="Add image to textarea" id="add_image" />
```

The CSS:

```
<style>
#message{
  padding-left : 30px; // This will prevent the text from overlapping the image
}
#add_image{
 display: block; //just making the button appear in its own line
}
</style>
```

The Javascript:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#add_image').click(function() {
      $('#message').css({
          'background' : 'url(http://lorempixel.com/20/40) no-repeat',
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

See it in action:
http://jsfiddle.net/gksTQ/